# Whats the root cause for "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE"?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I have the below method, but when ever i run the application I am getting following error:

 
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE"

```
 public static getExcludedEmailCount($email){
    db_set_active(TEST_DB);
    $sql = "select COUNT(*) from person WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX('%s','@',1) IN (SELECT email_role FROM email_role_exclusion)";

    $result = db_query($sql, $email);

    db_set_active();
    return $result;
}
```

Does anyone know whats the cause, I am quite new to Drupal and PHP. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put function. Declare like this

```
public static function getExcludedEmailCount($email)
```

Also the method inside getExcludedEmailCount belongs to the same class then use $this keyword, if they are belongs to another class, make object of that class and then access these methods.